# Data range filter not working in SQLite used in Android

Tags: android, datetime, android-sqlite

I am running SQLite to select data between two ranges for a created execution. To select the data from between two dates I use the following statement

```
 public ArrayList<LoopExecution> getDateRangeLoop(Date fromDate, Date toDate, int limit) {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM"
                + " loopexe "
                + " WHERE "
                + " created_on "
                + " BETWEEN " + fromDate.getTime()
                + " AND " +toDate.getTime();

     Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
     ArrayList<LoopExecution> loopExecutions = new ArrayList<LoopExecution>();
            if(cursor.moveToNext()) {
                do {
                    LoopExecution loopExecution = new LoopExecution();
                    loopExecution.setId(cursor.getString(0));
                    Date createdOn = new Date(cursor.getLong(1));
                    loopExecution.setCreatedOn(createdOn);
                    loopExecution.setCreatedBy(cursor.getString(2));
                    loopExecution.setLoopId(cursor.getString(3));
                    loopExecution.setLoopStatus(LoopExecution.LoopStatus.valueOf(cursor.getString(4)));
                    loopExecution.setImage(cursor.getString(5));
                    loopExecution.setResultJson(cursor.getString(6));
                    loopExecution.setBgImage(cursor.getString(7));
                    loopExecution.setTrendImage(cursor.getString(8));
                    loopExecutions.add(loopExecution);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();
            return loopExecutions;
        }
```

create query in SQLite database

```
public static final String CREATE_LOOP_EXC_TABLE = CREATE_TABLE + LOOP_EXC_TABLE_NAME
        + "(" + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "
        + CREATED_ON + "TIMESTAMP , " + CREATED_BY + "VARCHAR , "
        + LOOP_ID + "VARCHAR , " + LOOP_STATUS + "INTEGER NOT NULL, "
        + LOOP_IMAGE + "VARCHAR NOT NULL, " + RESULT_JSON + "VARCHAR , "
        + LOOP_BG_IMAGE + "VARCHAR , " + LOOP_TREND_LINE + "VARCHAR , "
        + "FOREIGN KEY(created_by) REFERENCES user(id) , "
        + "FOREIGN KEY(loop_id) REFERENCES loop(id) " + ")";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure your date format is **yyyy-MM-dd**
2. Try putting your dates inside **DATE()** flags

   ```
   String query = "SELECT * FROM"
               + " loopexe "
               + " WHERE "
               + " created_on "
               + " BETWEEN DATE('" +fromDate.getTime() + "') "
               + " AND DATE('" + toDate.getTime() + "') ";
   ```

Answer (score 0):

**Option one (if `created_on` is of type `INTEGER`):**

Since you want to use the long timestamp (just a number), which `getTime()` retrieves, you have to use the `<` and `>=` operators.

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM"
   + " loopexe "
   + " WHERE "
   + " created_on "
   + " >= " + fromDate.getTime()
   + " < " + toDate.getTime();
```

**Option two (if `created_on` is of type `TEXT`):**

You can use the [`BETWEEN`](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/between.php) operator but then you need to specify its arguments in a different format.

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM"
 + " loopexe "
 + " WHERE "
 + " created_on "
 + " BETWEEN '2017-07-10'"
 + " AND '2017-07-14'";
```

This is just an example with hardcoded dates. To make it dynamic use:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String date = formatter.format(today);
```